# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I created a simple rails project by following steps:

1. rails new .
2. rails g scaffold Post
3. rails g scaffold Puzzle
4. rails g model PostComment post_id:integer
5. rake db:migrate
6. rails g model PuzzleSave puzzle_id:integer
7. rake db:migrate

After step 5, rake test succeed. 
While after step 7, all rake tests failed with the same error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: puzzle_saves.created_at: INSERT INTO "puzzle_saves"
>   ("puzzle_id") VALUES (1)

How's this strange error happen? Isn't created_at field auto-generated? And I do not see any differences between the models created in step 4 and 6.

Environment:

- ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i386-linux]
- Rails 4.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got response from [github/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22450) (with similar issue for model Cave)

> Problem most likely stems from the fact that Rails is not able to pluralize / singularize the model name Cave:
>
> irb(main):003:0> "cave".pluralize
>
> => "caves"
>
> irb(main):004:0> "cave".pluralize.singularize
>
> => "cafe"
>
> This makes the Active Record Fixtures unable to detect the model for the generated caves.yml and hence created_at is not set.
>
> If you want to use models that Rails can't pluralize out of the box, have a look at the generated config/initializers/inflections.rb. Adding the following line before generating the scaffold should do the trick:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'cave', 'caves'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add created_at timestamp to `puzzle_saves.yml`:

```
# puzzle_saves.yml

one:
  puzzle_id: 1
  created_at: <%= Time.now %>

two:
  puzzle_id: 2
  created_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

This should fix those errors but I'm not sure why it's necessary, because this document claims that it should be done automatically
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

> Autofilled Timestamp Columns
>
> If your table/model specifies any of Active Record's standard timestamp
>   columns (created_at, created_on, updated_at, updated_on), 
>   they will automatically be set to Time.now.
>
> If you've set specific values, they'll be left alone.

PS. I checked and it also happens with PG database

Comment: Thanks. I got an answer from github. (see my answer below). this issue is in rails, so happens with all databases.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin, you've got the point! I had a similar issue and it was all about editing the fixtures (totally forgot about it) to conform my db constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Marcin Kornek solution is solid fallback, but for automatic setting timestamps in case You have **STI models**, nesting of fixtures is needed.

```
module Dog
  class Base < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name="dogs"
    belongs_to :owner
  end 

  class Baskerville < Dog::Base
  end

end
```

your fixtures must be set as:

```
fixtures/dog/baskervilles.yml
```

and with correct STI inheritace value set,
to properly load (including timestamps and named fixture associations)

```
little_b:
  type: "Dog::Baskerville"
  name: "Litte beast"
  owner: lord_baskerville
```

All fixtures will be loaded into `dogs` table.